# Created list from BeautifulSoup contains multiplicate entries -- need a unique link list

Tags: python, html, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a list containing all unique year links from a website (see below).

When I execute the append function it gives me a huge list containing dupli-multiplicate entries.

I need to get a list containing only the unique year links.

The website : https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/78-2021.html

Code written so far :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    import re
    
    URL = 'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/78-2021.html'
    
    headers1 = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36", 
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-61acac03-6279b8a6274777eb44d81aae", 
        "X-Client-Data": "CJW2yQEIpLbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEIuevKAQjr8ssBCOaEzAEItoXMAQjLicwBCKyOzAEI3I7MARiOnssB" }
    page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
    
    
    year = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=lambda href: href and "category" in href):
            print(link.get('href'))
            #year.append(link.get('href'))
            #print(year)
```

The desired result would look like this (but I need this in list format):

```
https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/78-2021.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/83-2022.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/78-2021.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/71-2020.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/4-2019.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/5-2018.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/6-2017.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/7-2016.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/8-2015.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/9-2014.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/10-2013.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/11-2012.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/12-2011.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/13-2010.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/18-2009.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/19-2008.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/20-2007.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/21-2006.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/22-2005.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/23-2004.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/24-2003.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/25-2002.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/26-2001.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/27-2000.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/44-1999.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/45-1998.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/48-1997.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/47-1996.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/46-1995.html
/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/49-1994.html
```

Edit : I am Trying to create a case list for every year in year list :
Code :

```
# 1) Created an year list (year = [])
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd
import re
total_cases = []

#Url to scrape
URL = 'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/78-2021.html'

headers1 = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-61acac03-6279b8a6274777eb44d81aae", 
    "X-Client-Data": "CJW2yQEIpLbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEIuevKAQjr8ssBCOaEzAEItoXMAQjLicwBCKyOzAEI3I7MARiOnssB" }
page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")


year = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=lambda href: href and "category" in href):
        if link.get('href') not in year:
            year.append(link.get('href'))
print(year)

# 2) Created a case list

case = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=lambda href: href and "apofasi" in href):
  if link.get('href') not in case :
            case.append(link.get('href'))

print(case)




#Trying to create a case list for every year in year list
# A)Get every year link in year list
for year_link in year :
    headers1 = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-61acac03-6279b8a6274777eb44d81aae", 
    "X-Client-Data": "CJW2yQEIpLbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEIuevKAQjr8ssBCOaEzAEItoXMAQjLicwBCKyOzAEI3I7MARiOnssB" }
    page = requests.get(year_link, headers = headers1)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
    print(year)
# B)Get every case link for every case in a fixed year
for case_link in case :
    total_cases.append(case_link)
    
#Get case link for every case for every year_link (element of year[])
???
```

**EDIT 2 :**

When I try to run the code you (HedgeHog) so kinldy posted it gives me this error :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
FeatureNotFound                           Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\ARISTE~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13944/1621925083.py in <module>
      8     "X-Client-Data": "CJW2yQEIpLbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEIuevKAQjr8ssBCOaEzAEItoXMAQjLicwBCKyOzAEI3I7MARiOnssB" }
      9 page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
---> 10 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')
     11 
     12 baseUrl = 'https://www.epant.gr'

~\Documents\conda\envs\conda\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py in __init__(self, markup, features, builder, parse_only, from_encoding, exclude_encodings, element_classes, **kwargs)
    243             builder_class = builder_registry.lookup(*features)
    244             if builder_class is None:
--> 245                 raise FeatureNotFound(
    246                     "Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you "
    247                     "requested: %s. Do you need to install a parser library?"

FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your expected result is not a list in the sense of [data structure][1], it is a printed version of each single element of a list. Could you describe, what you try to do with your `list` (covert to data frame, csv or really just printing), please.

Comment: My  fault, you can still use 'html.parser' I use 'lxml' as standard, so if you do not have installed it use 'html.parser' - It would be also a good idea, if your libraries are up to date

Comment: "I will edit this post here if I need some further help" - >

Would be better to ask a new question, to keep questions and answers clean.

Comment: Thank you, I will post the question tomorrow because I have reached the limit today. You have been a huge help! Have a lovely day!

Comment: New question sounds great - Note: rolled back your question version to your 2. edit, to improve make it bit shorter and clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

Based on your question edits I would recommend to use a `dict` instead of all this lists - Following example will create a data dictionary with years as keys, it´s own url and a list of cases urls.

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/78-2021.html'

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-61acac03-6279b8a6274777eb44d81aae", 
    "X-Client-Data": "CJW2yQEIpLbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEIuevKAQjr8ssBCOaEzAEItoXMAQjLicwBCKyOzAEI3I7MARiOnssB" }
page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

baseUrl = 'https://www.epant.gr'

data = {}

for href in [x['href'] for x in soup.select('a[href*=category]:has(span)')]:
    page = requests.get(f'{baseUrl}{href}', headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
    data[href.split('-')[-1].split('.')[0]] = {
        'url': f'{baseUrl}{href}'
    }
    data[href.split('-')[-1].split('.')[0]]['cases'] = [f'{baseUrl}{x["href"]}' for x in soup.select('h3 a')]
    
data
```

#### Output

```
{'2022': {'url': 'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/83-2022.html',
  'cases': []},
 '2021': {'url': 'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/78-2021.html',
  'cases': ['https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1578-apofasi-749-2021.html',
   'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1633-apofasi-743-2021.html',
   'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1575-apofasi-738-2021.html',
   'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1624-apofasi-737-2021.html',
   'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1510-apofasi-735-2021.html',
   'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1595-apofasi-733-2021.html',
   'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1600-apofasi-732-2021.html',
   'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1451-apofasi-730-2021.html',
   'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1508-apofasi-728-2021.html',
   'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1584-apofasi-727-2021.html',
   'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1586-apofasi-726-2021.html',
   'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/item/1583-apofasi-725-2021.html']},...}
```

---

#### How to fix?

Just check if the link is not in your list of links - So it is `True` append it to your list:

```
if link.get('href') not in year:
    year.append(link.get('href'))
```

**Note**

> The desired result would look like this (but I need this in list
> format)

This is not a list in the sense of [data structure](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) it is a printed version of each single element of a list.

Alternativ

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/78-2021.html'

headers1 = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-61acac03-6279b8a6274777eb44d81aae", 
    "X-Client-Data": "CJW2yQEIpLbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEIuevKAQjr8ssBCOaEzAEItoXMAQjLicwBCKyOzAEI3I7MARiOnssB" }
page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")


year = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=lambda href: href and "category" in href):
        if link.get('href') not in year:
            year.append(link.get('href'))

print(year)
```

#### Output

```
['https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/78-2021.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/83-2022.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/78-2021.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/71-2020.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/4-2019.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/5-2018.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/6-2017.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/7-2016.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/8-2015.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/9-2014.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/10-2013.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/11-2012.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/12-2011.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/13-2010.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/18-2009.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/19-2008.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/20-2007.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/21-2006.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/22-2005.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/23-2004.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/24-2003.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/25-2002.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/26-2001.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/27-2000.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/44-1999.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/45-1998.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/48-1997.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/47-1996.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/46-1995.html', '/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/49-1994.html']
```

Comment: Please take a look at the note in my answer and the comment below your question above - If you don't specify what the result should be, it's just a guess.  A list in Python is not represented in this way, as opposed to a string, csv,...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use a set as the intermediate storage for the HREFs then convert to a list later.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


URL = 'https://www.epant.gr/apofaseis-gnomodotiseis/itemlist/category/78-2021.html'

headers1 = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36",
            "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-61acac03-6279b8a6274777eb44d81aae",
            "X-Client-Data": "CJW2yQEIpLbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEIuevKAQjr8ssBCOaEzAEItoXMAQjLicwBCKyOzAEI3I7MARiOnssB"}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")


year = set()
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=lambda href: href and "category" in href):
    year.add(link.get('href'))
print(list(year))
```

Comment: I tred your soluion but it displays a list with no year based order and without any new lines between entries. Thank you for your time!

Comment: There was nothing in your question (that I could see) about providing output in any particular order. I refer you to [this](https://docs.python.org/3.9/howto/sorting.html)